# Convert DateTime string inside a class for Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, json, datetime

I'm trying to bind a JSON feed to classes for display in a XAML sheet. All of that works. However, one of the issues I'm having is converting a DateTime value (inputted as a string) into a different format.

For example, the JSON provides it as: "2014-04-20T02:57:00Z". I want to convert that into `"HH:mm"` format.

```
public String ArrivalTime
{
    get
    {

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(ArrivalTime);
        string test =  String.Format("{HH:mm}", dt);
        return test;
    }
    set
    {

    }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with the accessors and I'm pretty sure I've done it wrong, but on the right track I hope? How would I dynamically convert the incoming DateTime string into a new DateTime formatted string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you have the DateTime class convert 1397949540000 into some kind of valid date and time?

Comment: Sorry, very valid point. It should be "2014-04-20T02:57:00Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "WPF" way is to have the view convert it.  You can use IValueConverter interface to do the conversion of the data to how you want to show it.

You would need to put your logic in for what the number to date time should be.  Here is my guess.  I don't know how you could convert back being that you just have the time part and not the whole date time.  Also MarkupExtension isn't required it's just a nice to have.  See http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html for more information.

```
public class JSONDateToDate : MarkupExtension,  IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var jSONDate = parameter as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jSONDate))
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if DateTime.TryParse(jSONDate, out dt)
            {
                return dt;
            }
        }
        // If didn't pass in string or TryParse failed return back empty datetime
        return new DateTime();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Not needed just nice
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

In your XAML you would use it like

```
<TextBox Name="tbxArrivalTime" Text="{Binding Path=ArrivalTime, StringFormat=" \{0:HH:mm\}". Converter={x:JSONDateToDate } />
```

Just a word of warning I didn't test all this code and it might have some little issues in the XAML as it's hard to type without actually wiring everything up.

Updated my answer based on getting a date string instead of numbers back.   You can either in your IValueConverter return back the formatted string or you can return back a datetime.  If you return back a datetime then use the stringformat to format the value as a string.  If you have the exact format a lot of places I would put it in the value converter otherwise I would have my value converter just return back a datetime because I would probably get more reuse out of it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I opted to do it this way and it works much better! Didn't think to use the Converter... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is supposed to be a date/time, you should make sure it is. Just add another step to the deserialization of your feed to correct it and then it's just a presentation issue:

```
<TextBox Name="tbxArrivalTime" Text="{Binding Path=ArrivalTime, Format=\{0:HH:mm\}}" />
```

Comment: His datetime is actually in a string type.  He will still need a valueconverter to switch it from a string to a datetime.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I've added clarification to the answer.